# background color with an opaque image over the top

Tags: css, image, colors, background, transparent

I want to use a background color, along with a transparent (or opaque) background image.  Is this possible?

I've tried using div commands, but may be doing this wrong.  The only opacity command I can see is in CSS, but how do you link this specifically to the background image, rather than just the body content?

Comment: Please specify a programming language such as HTML or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for (run snippet to see):

```css
.stack{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position:relative;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png');
}

.base{
  filter: opacity(.3);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(.3);
}

.offset{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack">
  <div class="layer base">
  </div>
  <div class="layer offset">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added a margin to the top layer for you to see that there are two layer one (base) under the other. If you remove the margin you should see the tho images aligned perfectly.

Comment: I don't think I explained myself very well to be honest, sorry about that.

I want a black background, with a stretched image over the top (as a background image) but I want to make this faded (transparent) and then be able to add objects (solid ones) over it.

With the code you provided, when I try to add objects, it puts them above or below the image, unless I include them within the div, and then the same parameters (i.e opacity) are applied to them so they aren't solid.

Will I have to create the faded background image? or is there another way to around it?

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Comment: That's good, but then I can only use 1 solid image (the same as the background)

I need to put several different objects over the opaque background.

Sorry to be a pain in the ass.